# Coverity Scan for projects outside GitHub

Tags: coverity

I have been reading, but not yet found an answer.

I am very interested in using Coverity scan, but am not using Github (and didn't want to use travis-CI either as I have my own CI solution)

Is it possible to use Coverity scan outside of these tools? For instance a cli tool?

It seems that you must have a github URL to even register a project

Currently I am doing mostly PHP, JavaScript, node.js; but will soon add objective-c as well

Comment: Seems it is possible and a git URL is not required. Once the project is registered, the tools can be downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use GitHub and Travis CI. You can sign-up for Coverity account with just e-mail address and password, instead of with GitHub account, and you can add a project by filling out details form, instead of importing a GitHub project. Similarly, you can upload builds to Coverity Scan either manually or from your CI, instead of from Travis.

You have to Sign-up/Sign-in first at https://scan.coverity.com/users/sign_up, then you can open https://scan.coverity.com/download?tab=java (e.g. for Java) and get the software and instructions for doing the build.

If you want to use your own CI, you will get the info for doing both manual and automated build after adding a project at https://scan.coverity.com/projects/name-of-your-project/builds/new.

In essence, you can grab the build instrumentation tools either from the web site after logging-in, or by

```
wget https://scan.coverity.com/download/linux64 --post-data "token=<secret-token>&project=name-of-your-project" -O coverity_tool.tgz
```

(replace linux64 with your platform)

then you untar that and run the instrumented build

```
../cov-analysis-linux64-8.7.0/bin/cov-build --dir ../cov-int mvn -DskipTests=true package
```

finally tar the cov-int directory upload it with a HTTP POST request

```
curl --form token=<secret-token> \
  --form email=<your-email> \
  --form file=@tarball/file/location \
  --form version="Version" \
  --form description="Description" \
  https://scan.coverity.com/builds?project=<name-of-your-project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I suspected this might be possible.

Comment: I also wanted to clarify that under some open source licenses you do not have to release the source to the entire public. For instance if you have a private client, you may release the source only to them. In which case a private repo is still open source and so should be allowed under the Coverity rules! (For what it's worth I'd be happy to pay for coverity. But it's ridiculously expensive!)

Comment: There are decent alternatives, nowadays. For C/C++, there are some fancy analysis in Clion and Visual Studio. Clang and GCC have fancy warnings (-fanalyzer in GCC, some pedantic warnings, clang-analyzer in Clang, with good integration in macOS XCode to browse reports), and there are the sanitizers, now also in Visual Studio.